# I have a question about using extended_image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I ran into a problem while using flutter's extended image.

The image is rendered by putting the url in the getExtendedImage method, but if the url is newly updated, it is not reflected immediately, and the image is updated and rendered only when hot reload or other page is visited.

As soon as the url is modified, how do I get it reflected?

```
 AnimationController extendedController;

void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    NameController.text = GlobalProfile.loggedInUser.name;
    NickNameController.text = GlobalProfile.loggedInUser.nickName;
    PhoneNumController.text = GlobalProfile.loggedInUser.phone;
    // extendedController = AnimationController();
    super.initState();
    extendedController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        lowerBound: 0.0,
        upperBound: 1.0);
  }

//get_resize_image_name(GlobalProfile.loggedInUser.profileUrlList,120) returns url
getExtendedImage(get_resize_image_name(GlobalProfile.loggedInUser.profileUrlList,120), 0,extendedController),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setState(){} to update your widgets

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html